# Make Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express print its build commands

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, compilation

Is it possible to see which commands are actually executed by Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express when it builds a solution/project? I found out that in the `Configuration Properties` of a solution there is a `Command Line` window for both the compiler (C/C++) and the linker (Linker) but that does not really show all parameters (e. g. source and object/binary files).

I would like to see the commands in order to write a `nmake` build script that I can use to compile/link binaries for both the x86 and x64 platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the output of a Visual Studio build to be detailed. Go to menu *Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run*. Change the *MSBuild project build output verbosity* option, typically from the default *Minimal* to *Normal*, *Detailed* or *Diagnostic*.

Also take a look at *[/VERBOSE (Print Progress Messages)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdsk6as6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)* to set the linker output more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2010 and 2005

- View->Output or Alt+2
- Show output from: Build

For the compiler/linker parameters

- Project->Project Properties
- Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line
- Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Command Line

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually that only opens the output window, but it does not increase the verbosity.